# PHP and MYSQL sessions

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
require_once 'includes/config.php';
// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE name='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header("location:login_success.php");
}
$guest=1;
isset($_SESSION){
$guest=0;
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}?>
```

I have this code, but i don't know how to make an integer like... $guest or something like this, if $guest==1, the user is a guest else if $guest==0 the user is a logged member.
I've tried with isset but i failed, can someone help me?

Comment: I suggest you read/learn a bit more about PHP. This is basic stuff

Comment: Please be aware that the mysql extension (supplying the mysql_ functions) has been deprecated since 2012, in favor of the mysqli and PDO extensions. It's use is highly discouraged. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: sidenote `session_register` is [also deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php), check the date on the tutorial your learning from as it must be older then my nan

Comment: Use of session_register() is deprecated. Use of $_SESSION is preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
if( $_SESSION['myusername'] != null && $_SESSION['myusername'] != "")
{
$guest=0;
}
```

and so on...

Comment: And so on....? Really? If you're answering it, at least take the trouble to do it right.

Comment: Why not just use `if(!empty($_SESSION['myusername']))`?

Comment: I answered for a session issue only that would help him to continue

Answer (score 0):

You have Several problems in your code

1. You should [stop using `mysql_*` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) and start using `mysqli_*` functions or `PDO`
2. When ever you are going to use **SESSIONS** you need to call [`session_start()`](https://www.php.net/function.session-start) before using sessions
3. `session_register()` is deprecated
4. You cannot use simply $_SESSION. Write code like this

change this part

```
if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header("location:login_success.php");
}
$guest=1;
isset($_SESSION){
$guest=0;
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
```

to

```
if($count==1){
session_start();
$_SESSION['myusername'] = $_POST['myusername'];
$guest=1;
if($_SESSION['myusername'] == "" )
{
$guest = 0
}
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
```